# Applying flattened SPF records to DNS TXT records with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dns

In an attempt to reduce the number of DNS lookups occurring against our DNS SPF record I have written a PowerShell script which will extract out all of the allowed IP addresses from a SPF netblock (i.e. _netblocks.eloqua.com) and transforms it into this:

```
v=spf1 
ip4:129.145.16.0/24 
ip4:129.145.17.0/24 
ip4:129.145.18.0/24 
ip4:129.145.20.0/24 
ip4:129.145.21.0/24 
ip4:129.145.22.0/24 
ip4:129.145.23.0/24 
ip4:129.91.16.0/24 
ip4:129.91.18.0/24 
ip4:129.91.19.0/24 
ip4:141.145.10.0/24 
ip4:141.145.11.0/24 
ip4:141.145.12.0/24 
ip4:141.146.113.128/25 
ip4:142.0.160.0/20 
ip4:142.0.168.0/24 
ip4:142.0.174.0/24 
ip4:204.92.114.0/24 
ip4:204.92.19.0/24 
ip4:204.92.21.0/25 
ip4:204.92.22.0/24 
ip4:204.92.26.0/24 
-all
```

I have the values separated on each line to bypass the Windows DNS Manager TXT record character limitations. I also include a single whitespace character after each entry so it recognizes it as one TXT record properly.

I have all of that working. I can successfully write this to a TXT file (with CRLF endings), copy the contents, paste them into Windows DNS Manager on our DNS server and it will work.

But I want to automate it!

And that is where I am getting stuck. When I try to append the value as a string to the DNS TXT record using `Set-DnsServerResourceRecord` it presents me with the following error:

`Newinputobject for resource record has an invalid value. Failed to set the resource record on NHAEXDNS100.nhacentral.com server. Please check extended error for additional details.`

I've tried setting it into a Here string, writing it to file then using Get-Content to extract it with -Raw and get it out that way but it continues to give me this error.

I also tried extracting the data from the error to find this "extended error" data but I can't seem to find that extra data anywhere in the error object (you'll see my attempt to do so in my code).

Here is a snippet of the code I am using for reference:

```bsh
foreach ($flat_record in $flattened_spf_records)
{
    $index = [array]::IndexOf($flattened_spf_records, $flat_record)

    $current_spf_record = $null

    if ($index -gt 0)
    {
        $flat_record.DNSEntryValue | Out-File ".\$($flat_record.DNSRecordName).txt"
        Get-Content ".\$($flat_record.DNSRecordName).txt" | Out-File ".\$($flat_record.DNSRecordName)-Copy.txt"  # To change line endings from Unix style to Windows style for proper copying to Windows Server DNS

        Remove-Item ".\$($flat_record.DNSRecordName).txt"

        $DNSEntryValues = Get-Content ".\$($flat_record.DNSRecordName)-Copy.txt" -Raw

        $current_spf_record = (Resolve-DnsName ("$($flat_record.DNSRecordName).$($flat_record.DNSRecordZoneName)") -Type TXT -Server $dns_external_server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Strings -match "spf"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Strings) -join "`n"

        if ($current_spf_record -ne $DNSEntryValues -and [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($current_spf_record) -eq $false)
        {
            "Change detected on $($flat_record.DNSRecordName) in Zone $($flat_record.DNSRecordZoneName)."
            $old_domain_spf_record = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name $flat_record.DNSRecordName -ComputerName $dns_internal_server -ZoneName $flat_record.DNSRecordZoneName -RRType "Txt" | Where-Object {$_.RecordData.DescriptiveText -match "v=spf1" -and $_.HostName -eq $flat_record.DNSRecordName}
            $new_domain_spf_record = $old_domain_spf_record.Clone()

            $new_domain_spf_record.RecordData.DescriptiveText = $DNSEntryValues

            try
            {
                Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -NewInputObject $new_domain_spf_record -OldInputObject $old_domain_spf_record -ComputerName $dns_internal_server -ZoneName $flat_record.DNSRecordZoneName
            }
            catch
            {
                $err = $_

                $err | gm | ForEach-Object {
                    $name = $_.Name
                    $err.$name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have the SPF string value listed above automatically written into DNS so I can set my script up to run automatically via scheduled task and keep my SPF records up to date by IP address rather than by DNS lookups. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In general, when trying to get more info from error records, I find `$Error[0]|FL * -Force` to be quite helpful. Sometimes I have to repeat it with `$Error[0].Exception|FL * -Force` or the InnerException.

Comment: Nice trick! Thank you! Unfortunately the inner exception appears to be empty /facepalm

Comment: Have you checked the type and content of `$new_domain_spf_record.RecordData.DescriptiveText` to make sure it is a here-string with that same format?

Comment: If you want to use `Set-DnsServerResourceRecord` instead of the Windows DNS Manager, then why are you still flattening the record? :)

Comment: Concatenated with adding space in between the block of text above is 468 characters. DNS records can not be larger than 255 bytes so except if something split things automatically, your record can not be created as is. You will need to cut it down to 2 TXT records. Maybe that is the source of the issue, easy to test, try your script with a smaller list of IP addresses.

Comment: The byte limit is per string and each line is considered a separate string so you can extend the number of includes and ip4 allows with the method I am using above.

Comment: SPF records are only allowed 10 DNS lookups per domain name. If it goes over 10 your SPF record becomes useless because it never gets all the way to the -all.  If you use ip4 or ip6 instead of an include it won’t count against the dns lookup limit. So, to reduce the number of lookups and allow more room for services I pull out the IP addresses from the netblocks and put them in individually.

Comment: @general-gouda that makes sense, I misunderstood what you originally meant - can you share the SPF resolver/flattening code? It's a bit unclear what "this" is - a multi-line string, a string array, or?

Comment: You can subnet many of your /24 into /23 and /22 to reduce the size. That still won't put you below 255 characters. However, why not just have two records with the remaining IPs? Create one record called _spf with half of the IPs. Create a second record with the other half of the IPs and include the _spf. That is only one dns lookup.

Comment: If this is a one-time change, I don't see why automating is worth it here unless this is just a learning experience. This is one of those cases where you could have just done it in the GUI and moved on already. Been there done that unfortunately. I have attempted to replicate your issue and see the same problem. The only way that the problem goes away is for the record to be 255 characters or less based on my testing.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Here is a gist showing the flattener code.
https://gist.github.com/General-Gouda/7b8ff076ce46e658f7dff84d6c6df72a

Comment: @AdminOfThings The IP addresses and IP address ranges I am pulling out are coming directly from the netblock sources. Like in my OP the IP addresses shown are exactly what are listed as allowed in `_netblocks.eloqua.com`. 

The reason I would like to automate it is that larger allow records like the Eloqua one can change. If they add a new DNS lookup to their own SPF record then our DNS lookups increase as well. We've had trouble with this in the past because we are currently maxed out on our lookup allowance and adding any more makes it invalid and spam/spoofing start.